# Does Stack<> constructor reverse the stack when being initialized from other one?

Tags: c#, constructor, stack, reverse

Here is the code:

```
var s = new Stack<int>();
s.Push(1);
s.Push(2);
s.Push(3);
s.Push(4);

var ns = new Stack<int>(s);
var nss = new Stack<int>(new Stack<int>(s));
```

and then let's see the result

```
        tbLog.Text += "s stack:";
        while(s.Count > 0)
        {
            tbLog.Text += s.Pop() + ",";
        }
        tbLog.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        tbLog.Text += "ns stack:";
        while (ns.Count > 0)
        {
            tbLog.Text += ns.Pop() + ",";
        }

        tbLog.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        tbLog.Text += "nss stack:";
        while (nss.Count > 0)
        {
            tbLog.Text += nss.Pop() + ",";
        }
```

produces the following output:

```
s stack:4,3,2,1,

ns stack:1,2,3,4,

nss stack:4,3,2,1,
```

So, `ns` stack is reverted `s` stack and `nss` stack is the same as `s` stack.

Comment: This isn't a question, is it? ;)

Comment: Are you asking a question here? It appears that you are just posting some conclusion. Closing.

Comment: @Kieren, @Oded: I treat that as "I'm seeing something weird, is this right?" The question is in the title, the text is why is the Q being asked.

Comment: @Richard, that was a joke: my question was rhetorical.  Bad joke I guess!

Comment: @Kieren: OK, but one that could easily backfire: currently this Q has three votes to close as "not a real question".

Comment: guys, because of this i've lost 10$ in an hour (i'm working on trading robot), so it was very vital for me to ensure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The stack constructor which takes an `IEnumerable<T>` pushes the items on as if `Add` were called multiple times.

Iterating over a stack iterates in "pop" order... so when you construct one stack from another, it will add the top of the original stack first, then put the "second from the top" element on top of that in the new stack, etc... effectively reversing it.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor you are using for `ns` an `nss` is `Stack<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`. When you enumerate a stack it enumerates from top to bottom. But when creating a stack it pushes the elements in enumerated order. So the last enumerated item (last in the source) will be top of the new stack.

So yes, it does reverse the order of elements.

Comment: Calling `ns = new Stack<int>(s.Reverse());` would meet the OP's implied expectation.

Answer (score 3):

The clue to your surprise is in your question:

> Does Stack<> constructor reverse the stack when being initialized from **other one** ?

The ctor you are referring to does *not* accept another `Stack` - rather, it accepts an `IEnumerable`. That is, there is no special treatment for constructing a `Stack` from a `Stack`, as compared to constructing a `Stack` from any other `IEnumerable`.

So when you do try and construct a `Stack` from a `Stack`, the source `Stack` is consumed in its natural enumeration order, ie in the **popping** order. And the new `Stack` is constructed by **pushing** the items of the incoming `IEnumerable`. Hence the behaviour you are seeing.