# Reverse a Stack using an empty Stack and a variable v

Tags: stack

I am trying to reverse a stack using an empty stack and a variable v. But I am not getting the answer which I should Get. Can anyone please help me with this ?

```
void Reverse()
{

    S.push(1);
    S.push(2);
    S.push(3);


    int v;
    for(int i=1;i<S.size();i++)
    {

        v=S.top();
        S.pop();
        for(int j=0;j<S.size()-i;j++ )
        {
            T.push(S.top());
            S.pop();
        }
        S.push(v);

        while(!T.empty())
        {
            S.push(T.top());
            T.pop();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Stack is last-in-first-out (LIFO) non-generic collection of objects (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx). Thus, the simplest way to reverse the stack content is to create another stack, then pop entries from the original and push it to a new one. Rgds,

Comment: **Wait** what is `T` and where is it defined?

Comment: Also, your title is bad. It sounds like you want to reverse an _empty_ stack. In which case, there'd be no point.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is last-in-first-out (LIFO) non-generic collection of objects (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx ). Thus, the simplest way to reverse the stack content is to create another stack, then pop entries from the original and push it to a new one, like in the following example (pertinent to .NET/C# implementation):

```
Stack _stackOriginal = new Stack();
       _stackOriginal.Push(1);
       _stackOriginal.Push(2);
       _stackOriginal.Push(3);

Stack _stackReverse = new Stack();

while (_stackOriginal.Count>0)
{
_stackReverse.Push(_stackOriginal.Pop());
}
```

There is another solution found on this site ([Does Stack<> constructor reverse the stack when being initialized from other one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297717/does-stack-constructor-reverse-the-stack-when-being-initialized-from-other-one)), like the following:

```
Stack<int> _stackReverse = new Stack<int>(new Stack<int>(_stackOriginal));
```

Rgds,